# Why SQL UPDATE FROM silently fails when you refer to fieds with alias?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Yesterday I discovered something strange about SQL, or at least **PostreSQL**. Take a look below and explain why first query does nothing and the second one works just right.

```
-- this silently does nothing
update bodycontent 
    set body = replace(body, '~' || u.oldusername, '~' || u.newusername)
    from usermigration u;

-- this works as expected
update bodycontent 
    set body = replace(body, '~' || oldusername, '~' || newusername)
    from usermigration u;
```

Update: I think that everyone is missing the point on this question, the cartesian product was an original intent: there are going to be N x M updates and this is by design.

I need to replace all the pairs of usernames existing in the migration table in each row from bodycontent.

And, I repeat, the second version works as expected, but the first one does no update. All I wanted to know was why.

```
| usermigration table    |
--------------------------
oldusername | newusersname
--------------------------
johndoe     | johnd
john.smith  | johnsmith
```

Is this a bug in PostgreSQL?

Comment: It works for me. Show the data that reproduces the problem and the tables structure.

Comment: This was happening inside a big SQL transaction and this was one of the stepts. The migration table has only these two fields. The transaction succeeded but the bodycontent table was untouched! Changing to the second syntax (without u. solved the issue).

Comment: The statement itself is wrong. You are missing a join condition between bodycontent and usermigration (which has to be specified with a `where`). Currently your statement creates a cartesian join between the two tables.

Comment: Only **one** UPDATE is actually applied per row. You have a misconception of the workings of UPDATE statements there. Read the quote in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a **WHERE** clause (that cannot be written as direct `JOIN` condition). The additional table `usermigration` has to be bound to the table `bodycontent` to be updated in some way, or every row of `bodycontent` has as many update candidates as there are rows in `usermigration` - the cartesian product between the two tables.

There is no way to tell which one will be applied and persist. Both statements are wrong in this regard. For instance, if there are 1000 rows in `usermigration` and 1000 rows in `bodycontent` this will results in **1 000 000** updates candidates before 1000 can be picked.

If you join in one or more tables in an `UPDATE` statement it **hardly ever makes any sense** without a `WHERE` clause connecting the result of the `FROM` clause to the updated table.

Consider these **notes** in the [manual about the UPDATE statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html):

> When a FROM clause is present, what essentially happens is that the
>   target table is joined to the tables mentioned in the from_list, and
>   each output row of the join represents an update operation for the
>   target table. When using FROM you should ensure that the join produces
>   at most one output row for each row to be modified. In other words, a
>   target row shouldn't join to more than one row from the other
>   table(s). If it does, then only one of the join rows will be used to
>   update the target row, but which one will be used is not readily
>   predictable.

Note that the `FROM` clause in the `UPDATE` statement is a **PostgreSQL extension** to the SQL standard. Other DBMS use different syntax, for instance explicit `JOIN`s to the table to be updated (in tSQL) that do not work for PostgreSQL.

---

#### Answer to additional question in comment

This query should work, ***mostly***<sup>1</sup>

```
UPDATE bodycontent b
SET    body = replace(b.body, u.oldusername, u.newusername)
FROM   usermigration u
WHERE  b.body LIKE ('%' || u.oldusername || '%');
```

<sup>1</sup> The outcome is still **ambiguous**. Multiple matches can be found. It is uncertain, which one will be applied. The problem is that your **requirements are inherently ambiguous**. There can be multiple (overlapping) usernames that match and the **order** in which updates are applied is relevant (but not defined). The `UPDATE` statement perfectly reflects your flawed requirements.

And what's up with the `'~' ||` part?

Comment: @sorin: Actually, you are missing the point. The Cartesian product makes no sense at all in the UPDATE statement. It leads to random (implementation specific) updates picked out of the multiple possible candidates. Different results with syntax variants prove nothing in this case. (Deleted the last part about naming conflicts in my comment - that would raise an error.)

Comment: I am wondering how you would write an SQL query that replaces all pairs of old/new usernames from migration table in all body columns from bodycontent table.

Comment: @sorin: I added to my answer.